# Is there a plugin that will let me communicate with a PocketBase database?

Tags: javascript, nativescript, nativescript-plugin, pocketbase, svelte-native

I'm trying to connect with a running PocketBase database. Normally, I would use their Javascript SDK to achieve this, but the package does not get shipped to the mobile device during the build process.
This means I either have to build my own set of functions to mimic the working of the PocketBase Javascript SDK, or use a NativeScript plugin.

I could not find an existing plugin mentioning PocketBase, does anyone know of a plugin that facilitates this?

I tried to install the PocketBase Javascript SDK directly from NPM using `npm install pocketbase`, but this module does not check shipped to the mobile device during the build process.

For example:

```js
import PocketBase from 'pocketbase'
console.dir(PocketBase)
```

Running this from a NativeScript app logs "null" to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Using `import * as PocketBase from 'pocketbase'` ended up working for me.
I installed the pocketbase SDK with `npm i --save pocketbase`.

For whatever reason using `import PocketBase from 'pocketbase'` as the PocketBase documentation suggests doesn't work in this case.